# ActionbarSherlock with ViewPager with SherlockListFragments

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, android-viewpager

I have successfully implemented ActionbarSherlock on my first Android application and currently implementing ViewPager without much success.

The action bar currently contains two tabs, each of them loads up a SherlockListFragment.

The issue is that when the application loads, the first listfragment loads up and then very quickly the second listfragment replaces the first on screen.

If I swiping or clicking to the second tab, nothing appears.

It seems like the second listfragment replaces the first on screen.

Has anyone else ran into similar situation?

Thanks

Comment: post your work around...

Answer (score 0):

Instead of starting everything from scratch, you can first create a sample view pager projects that works, then slowly modify to include actionbarsherlock and others.

Go to File->new->project->Android application project. After a few next buttons before you click finish, there is an option called "navigation type". You can choose "Fixed tabs+swipe" or "Scrollable tabs+swipe" and click finish.

If you want to support api lower than 11, you can first set minimum api 11 so that the project is created, then modify the min api level in file manifest.xml after you modify the codes to include support library.

Answer (score 0):

Problem found!

For my SherlockListFragments update method, I had:

```
final ListView listview = (ListView) getActivity().findViewById(android.R.id.list);
```

The problem is that "getActivity()" will get the current Activity of the application, which is the overall SherlockActivity that is currently managing the ViewPager.

Therefore I have changed this to:

```
final ListView listview = (ListView) myCurrentView.findViewById(android.R.id.list);
```

where myCurrentView was set in my OnCreateView as:

```
View V = inflater.inflate(R.layout.contacts_list, container, false);
    myCurrentView = V;
```

Hope this will help another programmer in the future.